# Django HighChart with Api

Tags: python, django, highcharts

I'm new at Django please help me, I read some articles vlogs seems I cannot find the right code here's my code in **views.py** and i want it to disply in in HTML **index.html** and the result is it wont display I dont know what is wrong with my code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse,HttpResponse   
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json 


def home(request):
    response = requests.get('https:api').text

    # li = list(response.split(","))

    res = json.loads(response) 

    maleCount = 0
    femaleCount = 0
    for i in res:
        if i['gender'] == 'M':
            maleCount += 1 
        else:    
            femaleCount += 1
    TotalCount =[
        {
        "name": "MALE",
        "data": [maleCount]},
        {
            "name": "FEMALE",
            "data": [femaleCount]
        }
    ]


    return render(request,'index.html',{'data':TotalCount})
```

and here my code in html in index.html tru views.py it wont display my data in html seems my code wont work what is the problem of my code? please help thank you

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <body>


    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="border" id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
      </div>



    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

    <script>
        Highcharts.chart('container', {

            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['asd','asd']
            },

            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Number of fruits'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                        this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                        'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
                }
            },

            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal'
                }
            },

            series: data
        });
      </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use contextual data inside html code, you need to put this inside double brackets: 
`series: {{data}}`